# Cloudera Imala- Does it support Stored procdudre/ Function or SQL Blocks?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

Does Cloudera Imala- Does it support Stored procdudre/ Function or SQL Blocks like PL/SQL?

I have some logic to be built which will need multiple sql statements. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Impala only provides SQL.

You need to use some programming language or tools to build applications - SQL it self cannot be used. PL/SQL is traditional database programming language which runs in PL/SQL engine embedded in database. It reduces overhead between application server and database server, as the PL/SQL engine is embedded in the database. However, storage is network mounted and still data have to come to database server.

In case of big data technologies, there is not much beneficial of doing so. Even if you use Java, it will be running on all the nodes in the cluster and code goes to data. To build applications using Impala, you can just use Java with JDBC or you can even connect third party applications. Hence there is very little advantage of having programming language like PL/SQL.